# How to get json property name with php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

So here's the thing, I get this json from a url ( in my context i get it from a url, but let's say here I write my json in a variable :

```
   $file = '[
{"status": "5.4.1","email": "dddddd@exelcia-it.com"},
{"status": "5.4.1",, "email": "sksksksk@exelcia-it.com"}
]'
```

Then I do $json = json_decode($file,true);

And I want to get all the emails so I do :

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
  echo $value["email"]. "<br>";
}
```

But what I also need, is to return something like that from the loop (only for one property):

"email = dddddd@exelcia-it.com".
So I need to also get the name of the property but I can't figure this out.

I tried

```
foreach($json as $key => $propName){
    echo $key.'<br>';
}
```

But I just get the index (0,1,...), not what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Your json is invalid, so it already fails when you try to decode it.

Comment: Will this simple code work : `echo "email = ".$value["email"]. "<br>";` ? or it is dynamic ?

Comment: No I need it to be dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop each json row, this should works:

```
$file = '[{"status": "5.4.1","email": "dddddd@exelcia-it.com"},{"status": "5.4.1", "email": "sksksksk@exelcia-it.com"}]';
$json = json_decode($file,true);
foreach($json as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "<b>".$key."</b>".':'.$value.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this loop to get key and value pairs together.

```
foreach($data as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $key => $val)
    {
        echo $key . ': ' . $val;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks that's what I needed !

For me I just need the email properties and values, so I do :

```
foreach($json as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    {
        if($key=='email'){
            echo "<b>".$key."</b>".':'.$value.'<br>';
        }

    }
}
```

Awesome ! thanks !